# Official ubuntu 16.04 vagrant cloud image boots very slowly

Tags: boot, 16.04, virtualbox

I have a very powerful host machine running vagrant/virtualbox. I've installed the [official Xenial cloud image](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current/xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant.box). It starts very slowly, more than 3 minutes. If I see the log of virtualbox, there are a couple period, where nothing happens in tens of seconds:

```
00:00:05.306399 GIM: KVM: Enabled wall-clock struct. at 0x0000000002103128 - u32Sec=1490709692 u32Nano=164211738 uVersion=2
00:00:15.853501 PIT: mode=2 count=0x12a5 (4773) - 249.98 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:17.635954 APIC0: Switched mode to x2APIC
00:00:18.161514 PIT: mode=0 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:18.893709 CPUM: VCPU  1: Cached APIC base MSR = 0xfee00800
00:00:18.893902 APIC1: Switched mode to x2APIC
00:00:18.893941 GIM: KVM: VCPU  1: Enabled system-time struct. at 0x000000021ffed040 - u32TscScale=0xfffed226 i8TscShift=-1 uVersion=2 fFlags=0x1 uTsc=0x227f7943f uVirtNanoTS=0x113fa8853
00:00:40.767172 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#0: RESET, DevSel=0 AIOIf=0 CmdIf0=0x00 (-1 usec ago) CmdIf1=0x00 (-1 usec ago)
00:00:40.767323 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#0: finished processing RESET
00:00:40.770214 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#1: RESET, DevSel=0 AIOIf=0 CmdIf0=0x00 (-1 usec ago) CmdIf1=0x00 (-1 usec ago)
00:00:40.770323 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#1: finished processing RESET
00:00:57.578234 NAT: Link up
00:01:01.526079 LsiLogic#0: 2/0 (Bus/Target) doesn't exist
...
00:01:01.535077 LsiLogic#0: Guest issued CDB {0x12, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x24, 0x0}
00:01:24.478703 AIOMgr: Flush failed with VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER, disabling async flushes
00:01:32.045017 VMMDev: Guest Additions information report: Version 5.1.18 r114002 '5.1.18'
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You should also investigate the syslog from the virtual host to see if there is some kind of timeout happening.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem - also using the official Xenial cloud image - and I fixed it by adding this to my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "disconnected" ] # THIS LINE
end
```

As a result, the `ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log` file is not created on boot anymore, and the boot time is much shorter.